# OpenQuery SQL - What's wrong with my single quotes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery

When I exec this

```
SET @Qry =

    'SELECT [LMITNO] INTO ##TABLETEMP' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(@@SPID))) + '     
     FROM OPENQUERY(MAA,''SELECT DISTINCT [LMITNO] FROM MAA.ESMEL3.MVXDDTPRD.MILOMA 
     WHERE [LMITNO] LIKE ' + '''' + @ChemicalPreFix + '''' + ''')'
```

I get this.

```
    SELECT [LMITNO] INTO ##TABLETEMP91 FROM 
    OPENQUERY(MAA,'SELECT DISTINCT [LMITNO] 
    FROM MAA.ESMEL3.MVXDDTPRD.MILOMA WHERE [LMITNO] LIKE ''CHE%''')
```

But the error I get is that there is incorrect syntax near CHE%. However the syntax looks okay to me. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks right, except for the inclusion of the server name in the from statement, It should read as:

```
SET @Qry =

    'SELECT [LMITNO] INTO ##TABLETEMP' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(@@SPID))) + '     
     FROM OPENQUERY(MAA,''SELECT DISTINCT [LMITNO] FROM ESMEL3.MVXDDTPRD.MILOMA 
     WHERE [LMITNO] LIKE ' + '''' + @ChemicalPreFix + '''' + ''')'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
SET @Qry =

'SELECT [LMITNO] INTO ##TABLETEMP' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(@@SPID))) + '     
 FROM OPENQUERY(MAA,''SELECT DISTINCT [LMITNO] FROM MAA.ESMEL3.MVXDDTPRD.MILOMA 
 WHERE [LMITNO] LIKE ' + '''''' + @ChemicalPreFix + '''''' + ''')'
```

It gives the below query :

```
SELECT [LMITNO] INTO ##TABLETEMP53 FROM 
OPENQUERY(MAA,'SELECT DISTINCT [LMITNO] FROM  MAA.ESMEL3.MVXDDTPRD.MILOMA 
WHERE [LMITNO] LIKE ''CHE%''')
```

It is parsed successfully.
Extra quotes are required for the variable in the SELECT query as it is dynamic SQL.